# UnInitialized Constant error doesn't include the full namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the constant I have:

```
Book::Page::KIND
```

which is defined here:

```
class Book::Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    KIND = 0
...
end
```

and the model is in the proper location:

app/models/book/page.rb

The issue is that in one of my views which tries to render:

```
<%= Book::Page::KIND %>
```

I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Page::KIND
```

which is weird, cause it doesn't include the Book:: Prefix...

what's up with that? what can I do to help debug / fix this?

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.14

Comment: What if in your controller code you create an instance variable `@kind = Book::Page::KIND` and use it in your view `<%= @kind %>`? Does it give the same error?

Comment: in the controller, if I do ap `Book::Page::KIND`, it outputs `0` to the console... which is good. If I do as you suggest, it works. But what I had before was `"Book::Page::KIND".constantize`... and that made the error go away, and when I tried to remove it - I reloaded the page before inserting `@kind` - in suddenly started working™ (different error further down the page related to something else)... so.. I have no idea what happened there. =\

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, the view don't have the ability to instantiate constants like that, so when in the controller you have assigned, the view now knows the value of the constant. But that's just a maybe. xD

Comment: lol. maybe? It's my first time doing namespaces, so... I'll see how things turn out. =D